# Quick and dirty profiling for OpenGL compute shaders?

Tags: opengl, profiling, openframeworks, compute-shader

I have a GPU implementation of Marching Cubes for procedurally generated isosurfaces as part of a BSc project, implemented in OpenFrameworks using OpenGL compute shaders. It's up and running, debugged and working at decent frame rates, but I'd like to see if I can optimize it further and eliminate any potential bottlenecks (in particular, there are a lot of atomics in there and I'd like to find out if these are slowing it down much).

The algorithm uses 6 chained compute shaders with memory barriers in between :

1. get samples
2. get surface cubes (atomic counter)
3. get unique vertices (atomic counter)
4. get polygon indices (atomic counter)
5. get final vertex positions
6. get surface normals (lots of atomic adds)

Basically what I'm trying to find out is how long the algorithm spends in each separate shader, but the async nature of OpenGL makes this difficult. I installed GDebugger which comes highly recommended and was used to profile [this implementation](http://www.eriksmistad.no/marching-cubes-implementation-using-opencl-and-opengl/) which uses OpenCL for compute and OpenGL for rendering. Unfortunately it breaks my program. :-( The standalone exe works fine under Win7, but trying to run it inside GDebugger throws this for each shader:

```
[ error ] ofShader: checkProgramLinkStatus(): program failed to link
[ error ] ofShader: ofShader: program reports:
Compute info
------------
(0) : error C7006: no work group size specified
```

So I need an alternative way of profiling. I've considered doing something like this:

```
glMemoryBarrier(GL_BUFFER_UPDATE_BARRIER_BIT);
glMapNamedBuffer(someBufferIJustUsed);
cout << ofGetElapsedTimef() << endl;
glUnmapNamedBuffer(someBufferIJustUsed);
```

Hopefully this should block until the shader is done writing to the buffer , and give me at least a ballpark figure for completion time? But if anyone can point out a serious flaw in this approach or knows of a better way, please let me know.

Comment: Maybe [OpenGL Timer Queries](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/opengl-timer-query/) are what you need?

Comment: Yes! I didn't know these existed, but looks like just what i need, Thanks :-)

Comment: good question. Did BDL's suggestion work? is your code going to be public? do you have other info on this topic of cubes implementation on graphics card, i find it fascinating, to learn the theory first without having to decrypt all codes to do so.

Comment: I haven't got round to changing the code just yet, but it looks like it should work. The code is part of my BSc project so holding on to it for now, but I'll open-source it once it's submitted and graded.